# Are charitable donations on someone's behalf generally an effective incentive?

Tags: reference-request, behavioral-economics, experimental-economics

> A study done in Sweden on 153 female, would-be blood donors showed
>   surprising results. The women were divided into three groups–
>   voluntary donation, paid donation, and paid donation with the
>   immediate option to donate to children’s charity. Contrary to what you
>   might expect, the paid women decided to donate at a significantly
>   lower rate– only 30% compared to the 52% by voluntary donors and 53%
>   by paid-with-donation-option donors. The selfish reward “tainted” the
>   altruistic desire.

You can find the cited article [here](http://blog.silkroad.com/index.php/2013/10/intrinsic-vs-extrinsic-motivation).

The original article is Mellström, Carl, and Magnus Johannesson. "[Crowding out in blood donation: was Titmuss right?.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.319.3943&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" Journal of the European Economic Association (2008).

This one data-point suggests that donations on your behalf have no effect. Are there other studies that can help answer whether charitable donations on your behalf are

- valued
- as effective as other incentives (e.g. money)?